# Can't increase cpu cores on VBox vm

Tags: rhel, virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu

I imported a virtual machine from another host (the original host is using VirtualBox 5.0.16 and the new host is using VirtualBox 6.1.12). This virtual machine is installed with RHEL 4 32-bit version and had only 1 core.

After importing it from another host I tried to increase the CPU cores to 6 cores since the new host has more core. I enabled "Nested Vt-x/AMD-V", "PAE/NX", and "I/O APIC" in the machine's settings.

After starting the VM, I checked the CPU using "cat /proc/cpuinfo" but it only displayed 1 core:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor : 0 
vendor_id : Genuinelntel 
cpu family : 6 
model : 85 
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4214 CPU 2.20GHz
stepping : 7 
cpu MHz : 2193.857 
cache size : 16896 KB 
fdiv_bug : no
hlt_bug : no
fOOf_bug : no
coma_bug : no
fpu : yes 
fpu_exception : yes 
cpuid level : 22
wp : yes
flags : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht nx rdtscp constant_tsc pni popcnt 
bogomips : 4396.31
```

While dmidecode type 4 doesn't show anything

```
$ dmidecode -t4
# dmidecode 2.9
SMBIOS 2.5 present.
```

I tried to use [CPU hotplug](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#cpuhotplug) and it still doesn't work.

[Here's the info of the VM](https://pastebin.com/ctpr7BX1)

Comment: Is this the stock kernel (`uname -a`)? RHEL 4 had some early 2.6-era kernel. Can't even say whether that thing enabled SMP out of the box. I very vaguely remember a few distros having special "linux-smp" packages that you needed to use when you wanted that, but I never used RHEL 4.

Comment: `Linux <hostname> 2.6.9-89.EL #1 Mon Apr 20 10:23:08 EDT 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`. I'll try to look into it, thank you for the feedback.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: @cas Apologies, it's fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/871921/how-to-install-smp-kernel-on-rhel-4) source suggests there's a package called `kernel-smp` that you'd need.